# I am making a React App with CocktailDB API, but axios won't perform the GET request. The browser has no problem getting the resource

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am using createContext to send the State to the rest of the components. Because the app is small, I decided to put the Context and functions in the same file. I am using the free version of cocktailDB API, but axios won't get it. It says that it can't find the resource. I want to call the API only once.

ContextCategories.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

//Creating the CONTEXT
export const ContextCategories = createContext(); //Reference to the context

//Creating the PROVIDER
const CategoriesProvider = (props) => {

//Creating the STATE of the CONTEXT
const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);

//Calling the API
useEffect(()=>{
    const cocktailCategories = () =>{
       
        const URL = "www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list";
            const myCategories = axios.get(URL);
            console.log(myCategories);                            
    }
    cocktailCategories();
},[]);

return(                
    <ContextCategories.Provider
        value={{
          
        }}
    >
        {props.children}
    </ContextCategories.Provider>
);
};

export default CategoriesProvider;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you may need the http:// at the beginning of your url.

Comment: That was the error! It was a typo error, thank you so much for your help! @Kristian Martinez

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).